# Animating with setInterval in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

The question is how to get the train to return to the initial position by the second click.

Animation in this case is drawn from 0 to 400px in the left. I need a second click to draw from 400px to 0, so the train returns to its original position.

And why in this animation the train does not always matter in 400px, and how we achieve accuracy when using this function.

```js
train.onclick = function() {
  var start = Date.now(); // сохранить время начала

  var timer = setInterval(function() {
    // вычислить сколько времени прошло из opts.duration
    var timePassed = Date.now() - start;

    train.style.left = timePassed / 5 + 'px';

    if (timePassed > 2000) clearInterval(timer);

  }, 20);
}
```

```css
#train {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <img id="train" src="https://js.cx/clipart/train.gif">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do not rely on the interval. You should have 4 constants. start position, start time, end position and end time. Between that, make your code try to reach 30fps+ using requestAnimationFrame. For every frame you fetch the current time and you can use that to calculate the position the element should be at. When the frame "lags", no problem.. the next frame will catch up because it uses the fresh time for the calculation. For more info, read into "game loop",  use greensock or plain css and let the browser do this calculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modify your code and the code below works well:

```
window.onload = function() {
var train = document.getElementById("train");
var isLeftToRight = 0;
var startPosition = 0;

train.onclick = function() {
    isLeftToRight = 1 - isLeftToRight;
    var start = Date.now(); // сохранить время начала

    var timer = setInterval(function() {
    // вычислить сколько времени прошло из opts.duration
    var timePassed = Date.now() - start;
    if(isLeftToRight) train.style.left = timePassed / 5 + 'px';
    else train.style.left = (startPosition - timePassed / 5) + 'px';

    if (timePassed > 2000) {
        clearInterval(timer);
        startPosition = timePassed / 5;
    }
  }, 20);
}
```

Comment: Please improve your answer by explaining what you did.

Comment: When the train is moving from the left to the right: **train.style.left = 0, 4, 8, ...392, 396, 400**. After that, startPosition = 400. When it is moving from the right to the left: train.style.left = **400, 396. 392, ...,8, 4, 0**. So  `train.style.left = (startPosition - timePassed / 5) + 'px'`.

Answer (score 1):

The best thing about the new CSS spec is that you can leave all these things to CSS and use JavaScript purely for interaction. For example, the best way to do this is:

```
document.getElementById("train").onclick = function() {
  this.classList.toggle("end");
}
```

The above is the only JavaScript you need. Rest all magic is done by CSS. The good part about this is, it uses **GPU**, which is more efficient than CPU. See the snippet:

```js
document.getElementById("train").onclick = function() {
  this.classList.toggle("end");
}
```

```css
#train {
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: left 2s; /* Safari */
  transition: left 2s;
}
#train.end {
  left: 400px;
}
```

```html
<img id="train" src="https://js.cx/clipart/train.gif" />
```

For browser support, see [Can I use?](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions)

Comment: I completely agree with you. But I have another task, to realize with this function.